# Difference between two means and probability

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

If two populations are approximately normally distributed, such heights for men and women, and the means and standard deviations are known, can it be determined how often a man will be taller than a woman if one member from each population is randomly selected a large number of times?

Comment: If you ignore the fact that they are only approximately normal by knowing the means & variances exactly you then know the joint density of heights for men & women & just integrate it over the region where X>Y when X is the height for a man.

Comment: Your question seems to be about probability rather than likelihood. *Likelihood* has a specific, technical meaning in statistics that is quite distinct from the ordinary English usage where it essentially just means 'probability'; in statistics it *doesn't* mean probability, though it is connected to it. I have edited to remove the term, replacing it with *probability* so as to reduce confusion.

Comment: I believe this kind of question has been answered several times already; I'll see if I can locate a duplicate

Comment: What could you say about the distribution of the *difference* between the heights of a randomly selected man and woman?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261073/finding-probability-pxy

Answer (score 1):

Specific case: 
Let $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_X = 69, \sigma_X = 4)$ and, independently,
$Y \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_Y = 66, \sigma_Y = 3).$  I'm not saying this
is exactly correct for any populations of men and women (in inches), but it can
serve as an example.

Then, following @MartijnWettering's suggestion, let $D = X - Y,$ so that
$\mu_D = 3$ and $\sigma_D = \sqrt{25} = 5$ and thus
$D \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu_D = 3, \sigma_D = 5).$

Finally, $P(X > Y) = P(D > 0),$ which you should be able to evaluate (upon standarization)
using printed tables of the standard normal distribution. Alternatively, from R
statistical software, one has $P(X > y) \approx 0.726.$

```
1 - pnorm(0, 3, 5)
[1] 0.7257469
```

What area in the figure below represents the answer?

[image]

For the general case, show how to justify each step, and then how
to express the result in terms of the standard normal CDF $\Phi.$

---

*Note:* Simulation in R of a million choices of a man from the first
population and a woman from the second. Results should be accurate to
2 or 3 decimal places. [The vector `x > y` is logical with a million
`TRUE`s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is the fraction of its `TRUE`s.]

```
set.seed(918)
x = rnorm(10^6, 69, 4);  y = rnorm(10^6, 66, 3)
mean(x > y)
[1] 0.725808
```